# Что можно сделать, чтобы подмодуль на GitLab обновлялся автоматически?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodule

Я новичок в программировании и использую GitLab впервые:)

У меня есть проект, в котом мне необходимо пользоваться данными другого проекта. Я подключила его как подмодуль к своему проекту. Что я могу сделать, чтобы подмодуль обновлялся автоматически, как только в нем появляются коммиты?

Или есть более лаконичные пути решения данной задачи?

Comment: 1) не используйте подмодули 2) используйте менеджеры зависимостей

Comment: задавался ровно этим же вопросом, но потом понял, что текущее поведение правильное. Представьте себе, что сабмодуль может "неожиданно обновиться". А Вы в этот момент пишите свой код и тесты ганяете и тут раз... и не работает. Ещё раз - работает, а все потому, что кто то обновил свой репозиторий... другое дело, что git pull  мог бы  и подтягивать сабмодули до актуальных закоммиченных версий по умолчанию...

Comment: @KoVadim, см. `$ man git-pull` на предмет опции `--[no-]recurse-submodules[=yes|on-demand|no]`

Comment: @GaVAnt6 желание ваше вполне понятно и довольно распространено среди новичков. даже если бы это было технически осуществимо, делать так не стоит. KoVadim выше описал основную причину. дополню другими словами: если не фиксировать коммит подключенного хранилища, то рано или поздно там появится такой коммит, который поломает сборку вашего проекта. и пока вы не внесёте исправления в свой проект, сборка его будет сломана, и пользователи вашего проекта будут слать вам багрепорты. а представьте, что в подкл. проекте разработка идёт очень активно — ваш проект постоянно будет в «сломанном» состоянии.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я знаю о этой опции. Но когда я начал пользоваться сабмодулями, нужно было через цикл:). и второе - я не знаю, почему это не вынести в конфиг, что бы pull сам подтягивал сабмодули, без дополнительных параметров. А то как master  в main переименовать и натворить чудес - умеют, а как сделать что то удобное - это надо ревьювить, люди не поймут.

Comment: @KoVadim, посмотрите на опции `fetch.recurseSubmodules`, `submodule.<name>.fetchRecurseSubmodules` и `submodule.recurse`. по-моему, можно наконфигурировать так, как требуется. ну и alias-ы, конечно, наше всё.

Comment: алиасы - да. я в свое время делал просто баш скрипт и забыл.